# codeigniter update image not reuploading

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I'm running over this problem which I was trying for the last few hours
I'm having an image upload with some details to store in db.

I store the details and image path, working like a charm. Now comes the edit part.
I'm trying to check if the input file is empty, if so update just the details, else delete the image and reupload new image. The problem is this:

If the input file is empty it updates everything no problem, if is not empty it is updating the details, but the image is the same, doesn't get deleted or reuploaded.
here is the code

```
$image_input = $this->input->post('image');
    if(isset($image_input) && !empty($image_input))
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $img = $this->db->get('menus_category', 1);
        if($img->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $row = $img->row();
            $original_image = $row->image;
            $desktop_image = $row->desk_img;
            $mobile_image = $row->mob_img;
            $thumb_image = $row->thumb;
            $unlink_image = unlink('./uploads/menus/' . $original_image);
            $unlink_desk = unlink('./uploads/menus/desk/' . $desktop_image);
            $unlink_mob = unlink('./uploads/menus/mobile/' . $mobile_image);
            $unlink_thumb = unlink('./uploads/menus/thumbs/' . $thumb_image);
            if($unlink_desk && $unlink_image && $unlink_mob && $unlink_thumb)
            {
                $config = array(
                'upload_path' => './uploads/menus',
                'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
                'max_size' => '15000'
                );
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
                {

                    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

                    $this->load->library('image_lib');
                    // thumb resize
                    $thumbnail = 'thumb_' . $image_data['file_name'];
                    $thumb = array(
                        'image_library' => 'GD2',
                        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
                        'new_image' => $image_data['file_path'] . 'thumbs/' . $thumbnail,
                        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
                        'width' => '90',
                        'height' => '90'
                    );
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($thumb);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                    $this->image_lib->clear();

                    // mobile resize
                    $mob = 'mob_' . $image_data['file_name'];
                    $thumb_mob = array(
                        'image_library' => 'GD2',
                        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
                        'new_image' => $image_data['file_path'] . 'mobile/' . $mob,
                        'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
                        'width' => '290',
                        'height' => '83'
                    );
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($thumb_mob);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                    $this->image_lib->clear();

                    // desktop resize

                    $desk = 'desk_' . $image_data['file_name'];
                    $thumb_desk = array(
                        'image_library' => 'GD2',
                        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
                        'new_image' =>  $image_data['file_path'] . 'desk/' . $desk,
                        'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
                        'width' => '700',
                        'height' => '200'
                    );
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($thumb_desk);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                    $this->image_lib->clear();

                    // insert path and details to database
                    $data = array(
                        'title' => $input['title'],
                        'slug' => $this->_check_slug($input['title']),
                        'description' => $input['description'],
                        'image' => $image_data['file_name'],
                        'desk_img' => $desk,
                        'mob_img' => $mob,
                        'thumb' => $thumbnail
                    );
                    $this->db->where('id', $id);
                    return $this->db->update('menus_category', $data);
                }
                else 
                {
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $data2 = array(
            'title' => $input['title'],
            'slug' => $this->_check_slug($input['slug']),
            'description' => $input['description']
        );
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->update('menus_category', $data2);
    }
```

Note: the else statement works fine, but the first if the problem. Now I changed the if to just if(isset($image_input)) ... and if file input is not empty is reuploading the picture and updating the details fine, but if I update only the details with no picture, it is deleting the picture that is already uploaded and is not updating. (I think this is the problem but I can't figure out how to fix it).

If you will to give me some help or to put me on right direction I will be thankful.
Thanks guys

Comment: any kind person out there?

Answer (score 1):

First, this would be a comment asking a question, but I don't have enough reputation do add one just yet...
If you could post your HTML form, that would be helpful, but without that...

1) I assume the form you are submitting has enctype="multipart/form-data" in the opening tag.
2) On line 2 of your code here, *$this->input->post('image')*, is 'image' from a form input of type file? If so, your statement won't work as 'image' is part of the $_FILES array and not $_POST anymore. Meaning when you go to check it, it is always going to be empty (or non-existent).

To verify that your form is submitting the way you think it is, do this just before the first line in the code you have in your post:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
exit; // don't let anything run after the dumps.
```

let me know if that puts you in the right direction or not.

Comment: hi ryan, thank you for answer but i solved the problem myself not long time after i posted, i used another method which works fine for me :)